# Flink UI Overview

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-streaming

I have a flink UI dashboard and under the  overview tab I see a box with the following text. Just want to understand what it means.

Source : Custom Source -> Timestamps/Watermarks -> FlatMap -> ParDo(SomeMethodNameInJava) -> (ParDo(SinkMetric),ParDo(KafkaWriter)) Parallelism : some number.

Just want to understand how to read the above text of information . ( I understand the concept of ParDo etc )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using Apache Beam(ParDo). What exactly do you want to understand about this text? Do you want to understand why your Beam program was translated to this execution plan?

In general this text describes what is executed in a task (this chain of operators). For some context information on Flink's runtime you can read this [page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/concepts/runtime.html)

Comment: Thanks! I guess I wasn't sure where the first TimeSeries/Watermark means .